# git deployment: untracked working tree files overwritten by merge

Tags: git, deployment

I'm trying to implement a git based deploy procedure like in http://danbarber.me/using-git-for-deployment/ to deploy a web application.
Basically it consists of two repos on the live server:

- a bare repo, in which you push, the "hub"
- a normal repo in the web server public directory, in which you pull from the "hub". This is performed automatically if the hub has an
  appropriate post-update hook.

The problem is that in my projects I have many directories, like /upload/, which contain sample data during development and real live data on the webserver.

Ideally I would like to keep the upload/ folder on local repo, but not pulling it on the live repo.
Now, "partial" pull it doesn't seem possible, isnt'it?

So, even if not an optimal solution (I can't clone sample data in local repos),  I'm trying to ignore those folder, but:

- I added the upload/ folder to .gitignore on local and live repos.
- I removed it with git rm --cached upload/
- I pushed the project to the bare "hub" repo
- in the live repo I pull from the hub
- I get the error: untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge...upload/xxx

It seems to me that the upload/ folder is still somewhere...
Indeed, while writing this, I see that cloning from the hub, the folder upload/ is cloned too!

The only solution would be then, to remove completely the folder from all the project history, like I've seen in several questions?

Is this going to force all the others colleagues working on different branches to some messy rebase?

It's probably difficult to explain all this and to grasp it, but any idea is welcome.

Comment: `git rm --cached` only removes the file from index, which means what is going to be commited next. It doesn't actually remove the file, nor does it mark them for a remove in the next commit. It would only do something if you have done `git add upload/*` (and not commited), otherwise it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do all that, assuming you wouldn't want to checkout an older commit than the head of your branches.

What you need to do is to eliminate `upload/*` in a new commit, and from then on, anyone seeing the new commits wouldn't see the `upload` directory.

Obviously, you would want to back the `upload/*` files up on the "hub" *and* on any clone who would pull from it, remove upload in a commit, and then put the backup back in its place. Now the data exist in your directories, but git wouldn't be tracking them anymore.

Note: if you don't backup, you would be deleting the `upload/*` data on hub (recoverable by checking out an older commit) or anyone pulling from it (error by git if they are not tracked, or recoverable by checking out an older commit if tracked). Nevertheless, better just back it up first.

---

Example:

```
$ git init
$ mkdir upload
$ echo 'upload/*' > .gitignore
$ touch to_track upload/not_track
$ git add .gitignore to_track upload/not_track
$ git commit
```

Now you have `upload/not_track` in the repository.

```
$ cp upload/not_track ../backup
$ git rm upload/not_track
$ git commit
$ mv ../backup/not_track upload/
```

Now the files in the current directory haven't changed, but `upload/not_track` is not in the repository any more (from this commit forward).

Comment: wow, good insight, easy and clear solution! I didn't think about it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to be sure without seeing the git repo, but what you're describing should not be happening.

Have you checked the folder for hidden files (for example, a `.gitignore file` in there, or `.DS_Store` (Mac folder browser cache) or similar?). Ignored files are not removed automatically by `git rm`.

If you git ignored before you `git rm` you'll have to either remove it from ignore, or straight `rm` it.